# Content type dropdown not displayed django admin form

Tags: python, django

This is a Post model and when I open it in django admin to add posts, I see a field content type but there exist no drop-down to select the content type. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
class Post(models.Model):

    FEATURE_LIMITS = models.Q(app_label=u'forums', model=u'forum')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=FEATURE_LIMITS, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

*admin.py* for **posts**

```
# imports

admin.site.register(posts_models.Post)
```

There is a model Forum, which has a generic relation with post.

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    # other fields
    posts = GenericRelation(Post)
```

The post field is not visible on django admin(other fields are visible).

*admin.py* for **forums**

```
# imports

admin.site.register(forums_models.Forum)
```

If I make changes to admin.py :

```
class PostInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Post

class ForumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PostInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(forums_models.Forum, ForumAdmin)
```

Then on hitting `http://localhost:8000/admin/forums/forum/add/`, the page keeps loading forever.

Comment: But why do you need to create generic relation for only one model? Generic relations are not efficient for that stuff..

Comment: I expect for sure to add more models in future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you configured your application wrong.

My project structure

```
app
|-settings/
|-forums/
|--models.py
|--admin.py
|-posts/
|--models.py
|--admin.py
```

So **posts/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    FEATURE_LIMITS = models.Q(app_label='forums', model='forum')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=FEATURE_LIMITS, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

**posts/admin.py**

```
from .models import Post

class PostInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Post
```

**forums/models.py**

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    # other fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    posts = GenericRelation('posts.Post')
```

**forums/admin.py**

```
from .models import Forum
from posts.admin import PostInline

@admin.register(Forum)
class ForumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PostInline,
    ]
```

And everything works like a charm.

I have a guess you have infinite loop because tried to register models in the wrong app.(model `Forum` in app `posts`)

Comment: I am working on it, this is a copy paste and thus may have mistakes, dont worry about directory structure, that's perfectly fine. I have overriden django admin, and that's the culprit.

Comment: @rohanagarwal i've tried that solution by myself and it's working(just for you to know that this is not some code written without trying)

Comment: You are right. I know the code you wrote works because you are using django.contrib.admin. I have overriden this admin and hence the problems. If I write the code in the question in a new project, that too will work, because admin won't be overriden in a new project.
 **this is a copy paste and thus may have mistakes** is for the code I posted, as I can't post the original code

Answer (score 0):

I was using `admin.widgets.ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` [widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py) which prevented foreign key fields to display normally. Since

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=FEATURE_LIMITS, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

content_type is a foreign key field, there was no dropdown.
To prevent this from happening, make following changes in admin.py:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_field_excludes = 'content_type'

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```